# AgentSet cannot be resolved to type in Repast Simphony model

Tags: eclipse, repast-simphony

I've installed Repast Simphony on Eclispe (centos 7.7) and I'm trying to run the Zombies demo but seeing errors like the following:

````
AbstractGridFunction cannot be resolved to a type   Heatbug.java    /Heatbugs/src/repast/model/heatbugs line 58 Java Problem
AbstractPointTranslator cannot be resolved to a type    SwarmBuilder.java   /Flock/src/flock/agents line 41 Java Problem
AbstractReLogoPanelCreator cannot be resolved to a type ReLogoPanelCreator.java /Zombies_Demo/src/zombies/factories line 7  Java Problem
AbstractStyleVisitor cannot be resolved to a type   BlueCoverageStyle.java  /Geography/src/geography/styles line 25 Java Problem
AgentAnnot cannot be resolved to a type SimpleAgent.java    /PredatorPrey/src/PredatorPrey/agents   line 19 Java Problem
AgentSet cannot be resolved to a type   ReLogoLink.java /Zombies_Demo/src-gen/zombies   line 25 Java Problem
AgentSet cannot be resolved to a type   ReLogoLink.java /Zombies_Demo/src-gen/zombies   line 26 Java Problem
AgentSet cannot be resolved to a type   ReLogoLink.java /Zombies_Demo/src-gen/zombies   line 26 Java Problem ```
 

Any suggestions on how to resolve this are appreciated.
Ed Hall
````

Comment: Was there anything you did that diverged from the Linux install instructions here? https://repast.github.io/download.html#update-site-install

Comment: No, I followed the instructions on that page exactly. I did the install 4 months ago on this machine w/o problem. I'm not sure what has changed, but I appreciate any tip for what to look at.

Comment: Interesting, so this had worked before? In that case one thing you could try is to use a new workspace, in case something got corrupted in the one you're using.